# Drawing multi-coloured manifold in IPE draw

Tags: ipe

I am trying to create this in IPE draw:

[image]

However I am finding this somewhat difficult, as it is not clear to me how to cut the spline into multi-coloured segments.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you doing this completely with `ipe` or is Latex involved in any way in the creation of the image?

Comment: I was hoping to not get Latex involved.

Answer (score 1):

You could make three copies of your Splinegon, make each of them a group and [clip](http://ipe.otfried.org/manual/manual_19.html) this group using the splines defining your partitioning

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.